# write and read file in onClick switch case Statement in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hey guys as I said above i have a problem with writing a file to the internal storage of the phone in a switch-case statement inside an `onClick()` method inside a `Fragment`. I know this sounds pretty complicated. I want to make a little calculator that can tell you how many litres of gas you needed to drive 100 kilometres.

So I thought I'll make a very simple one that only works if the the person always fills up the tank of the car fully so when used the first time they have to give me the kilometres of their cars and when they tank the next time they give me the kilometres again + how much litres gas they needed to fill their tank fully then I want to read out the file where the first kilometres are saved and calculate the difference and then use the driven kilometres to calculate the gas / 100 kilometres.

But my problem right now is how I can call the `saveInInternalStorage()` method inside the switch-case statement.

I hope you can help me.

So here is the `Fragment`:

```
public class FragmentFuel extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

  EditText kil;
  EditText fuel;
  Button calc;
  String filename;

  public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        FragmentFuel f = new FragmentFuel();
        return f;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel, null);
        Button b = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calcFirstTime);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
              case R.id.calcFirstTime:
              saveInInternalStorage(v, getActivity());
              break;
        default:
              break;
        }
  }

  public void saveInInternalStorage (View view, Context fileContext){
        kil = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.kilometres);
        String dataToSave = kil.getText().toString();
        String FILENAME = "myFile";

    try {
              FileOutputStream fos = fileContext.openFileOutput(FILENAME, fileContext.MODE_PRIVATE);
              fos.write(dataToSave.getBytes());
              fos.close();
              Toast.makeText(fileContext,"Text Saved !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(fileContext,"Error FileNotFound!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
              Toast.makeText(fileContext,"Error IOException!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }

}
```

ok I remodelled my Fragment a little bit to find the Error I am pretty new to android so I really don't know what you meant with implementing the view in the onCreate.
And the hint with the NuLLPointer is also correct. And the Error is if I give some Input to my Edittext and then press the button so that it should get displayed in the Toast the whole app breaks down.

```
public class FragmentFuel extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

EditText kil;
EditText fuel;
Button calc;
Button calcFirstTime;
String filename;

public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    FragmentFuel f = new FragmentFuel();
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel,
            null);
    Button bu = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calcFuel);
    bu.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button b = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calcFirstTime);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);


    return root;

}



@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.calcFirstTime:
        anything(v);
        break;
    case R.id.calcFuel:
        //saveInInternalStorage(v, getActivity());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

public void anything(View view){

     kil = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.kilometres);
        String dataToSave = kil.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataToSave,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

12-30 18:15:34.355: D/libEGL(6048): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so

```
12-30 18:15:34.365: D/libEGL(6048): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so

12-30 18:15:34.375: D/libEGL(6048): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so

12-30 18:15:34.375: D/libEGL(6048): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so

12-30 18:15:34.435: D/OpenGLRenderer(6048): Enabling debug mode 0

12-30 18:15:49.660: D/AndroidRuntime(6048): Shutting down VM

12-30 18:15:49.660: W/dalvikvm(6048): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab7228)
12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048): java.lang.NullPointerException

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at at.****.routelogbook.FragmentFuel.anything(FragmentFuel.java:92)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at at.****.routelogbook.FragmentFuel.onClick(FragmentFuel.java:74)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

12-30 18:15:49.670: E/AndroidRuntime(6048):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 92 is:
`String dataToSave = kil.getText().toString();`

and Line 74 is where the anything method gets called in the switch case statement

Comment: what is the problem? any excpetions??

Comment: looks good, what is the problem?

Comment: Why not using the shared prefs?

Comment: What is line 92 `FragmentFuel.java` and where is `anything(View view){` called

Comment: do check my edit and see if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a view in `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel,
        container,null);

Button b = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calcFirstTime);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
return root; // missing

}
```

I further suspect a `NullPointerException`. Post the stacktrace

I guess line 92 is

```
String dataToSave = kil.getText().toString();
```

`kil` being null

SO i suggest

```
EditText ed;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fuel,
            container,null);
    ed = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.kilometres);
    Button b = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.calcFirstTime);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return root; 
    }
```

Then

```
 anything();
```

Then

```
public void anything(){
    String dataToSave = ed.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataToSave,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Holy Macaroni thank you so much !!!!!!!! I really wasn't expecting such good and quick help so I am really thankful :)